# Vercel Vite, cannot find type definition for "vite/client"

Tags: typescript, vite, vercel

I'm trying to deploy to vercel using vite but I keep getting the following error:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'vite/client'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'vite/client' specified in compilerOptions
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 2
```

I've tried adding:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/"]
```

And installing different vite versions: v4.4.0 and v4.1 but the problem continues.

Here's my client-side package.json, any ideas:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's uncertain why the problem causes, but I think you have to double check:

- I'm not sure if this is required to tsconfig.json "types": ["vite/client"].
  Do you have a `vite-end.d.ts` file in your root folder yet? If not, try to create one with

```html
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

- If you're deploying to cloud service, check if the CI npm install is running correctly. Make sure it also runs devDependencies if your Vite is in the devDependencies list.

P/s: The error message clearly said that it cannot find the type for vite/client. Remove "vite/client" from that list, add my step 1 and try to deploy again. If it does not fix the problem, try no 2. If not again, try to correct "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/vite"] since Vite type is not from node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me insane until Vic Nguyen's post led me to read about `vite-end.d.ts`.

You can see more documentation here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#intellisense-for-typescript

In the context of my issue, my Sanity / NextJS build also had an unnecessary Vite entry in `compilerOptions` outside of Sanity.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35713044)